# Is it possible to make a loop in javascript that acts like a loop in a batch file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file

So I was making loops in a batch file which just keep going until you stop it. I wanted to do this in Javascript, but I wouldn't know how, because my understanding is that Javascript loops are only run once, and it only shows the output of the loop once.

Here is my loop:

```
@echo off
:loop
echo Hello!
goto loop
```

So when I put this into a batch file and run it, it will spam 'Hello!' until I close the program. That's what I want Javascript to do, but I don't quite know how to do that, and any help or input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @Zachuks Javascript is browser based language. It has nothing to do with desktop application like batch files. What is your exact expectation about Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true) {
  // echo hello
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by simple while loop;

```
while(true){
   document.write("Hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (1) {
  document.write("Hello!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more sensible scheme than a "raw" endless loop is to use the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions to make the browser not block while your code is running:

```
function fancy_output_func() {
    // bla
}

setInterval(fancy_output_func, 0);
```

Comment: I think this is what I want, because I did just the loop, and it won't load any content when I run it. Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to refrain from actually using a `0` there, this value is the interval in milliseconds so `100` should be enough most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there are some more ways to do that but here a a few

```
for(;;) { 
    //endless loop
}

while(1) {
    //endless loop
}

function a() {
    //endless loop
    a();
}
```